# How to inline list in mvc

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have list in mvc to which I want to inline in blocks.

**List-**

```
 <ul>
     <li>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
  <img src="@item.cardFilePath"/>
}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS** I tried here-

```
li
{
list-style-type: none; 
display: inline-block; 
float: left;
margin: 0px 24px;
padding-left: 24px;
}
```

Basically there will be images to inline coming dynamically via list through model.

How do I inline these images coming in list form.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle? It would be easy to debug jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be the problem? Try using this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PBrU8/)**

```
    <ul>
    @foreach(var item in model)
    {
        <li>
            <img src="@item.cardFilePath" />
        </li>
    }
    </ul>
```

---

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
}
ul li {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    margin-right:10px;
}
ul li:last-child{
    margin-right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code.. here is the fiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/PBrU8/15/

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block; 
    margin: 0 5px 0;
}
```

Why I prefer here using `display:inline-block` over `float` please read this article.

http://www.sitepoint.com/give-floats-the-flick-in-css-layouts/